# Elasticsearch _geo_distance Sorting Error

Tags: sorting, geolocation, elasticsearch

Greetings Overflowers,

Why am I getting this error by elasticsearch (1.2.2) using the official nodejs client?

```
Parse Failure [No mapping found for [[object Object]] in order to sort on]]
"sort":[{"_score":{}},{"[object Object]":{}}]
```

Here is my query (in JSON format):

```
{
    "index":"myidx",
    "type":"mytype",
    "body":{
        "query":{
             "filtered":{
                  "filter":{
                      "and":[
                          {"term":{"to":"WORLD"}},
                          {"or":[
                              {"term":{"invisible":false}},
                              {"term":{"user":"@geeko"}}
                          ]},
                          {"term":{"blocked":false}}
                      ]
                  },
                  "query":{"terms":{"text":["world"]}}
             }
        }
    },
    "sort":[
        "_score",
        {"_geo_distance":{"mytype.location":"0.0,0.0"}}
    ],
    "from":0,
    "size":20
}
```

BTW, all of my mappings are defined (specifically mytype.location is geo_point), and this query works if I remove the _geo_distance sorting.

Kind regards

UPDATE (Mappings and Samples):

```
{
    "template": "myidx",
        "mytype": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": {
                "id": {"type": "long"},
                "timestamp": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "date_time"
                },
                "location": {"type": "geo_point"},
                "user": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "text": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "simple"
                },
                "to": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "invisible": {"type": "boolean"},
                "blocked": {"type": "boolean"}
            }
        }
    }
}

{
    "id":"1",
    "timestamp":"2014-08-07T20:35:40.936Z",
    "location":"10.0,10.0",
    "user":"@geeko",
    "text":"Hello World!",
    "to":"WORLD",
    "invisible":false,
    "blocked":false
}
```

Comment: This is working for me. I am able to sort, Can you give me curl request? Because I cant replicate after having mapping and data also.

Comment: Are you sure you defined your mapping BEFORE inserting any data?

Comment: Yes, because if I remove the _geo_distance sort, everything works fine with other type of sorts. Is it working with you?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it turned to be from my improper use of the nodejs client.
I was using the sort property provided with the search function of the client (which is equivalent to in-url sorting that do not accept objects like _geo_distance) where I should have used the sort property in the query body.

Comment: Can you please provide the working code that you used to fix the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Just move sort inside body next to qurry